# Unable to Update rsyslog using Ansible

Tags: ansible, rsyslog, devops

I am having production systems which are running on outdated rsyslog version 7.4.4, hence I need to update using latest v-8 version , as in  http://www.rsyslog.com/ubuntu-repository/
Only 3 things need to be done

```
1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adiscon/v8-stable
```

{After This step, it asks to press [ENTER]

```
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install rsyslog
```

so i wrote the following tasks in playbooks as:

```
- name: Updating rsyslog from 7.4.4 to v-8 stable| Adding PPA 
  apt_repository:
    repo='ppa:adiscon/v8-stable'
    state=present
    update_cache=yes

- name: Running Updates
  apt: update_cache=yes

- name: Install rsyslog (v-8)
  apt: name=rsyslog 
       state=present 
       update_cache=yes
```

at the first task Ansible{Updating rsyslog from 7.4.4 to v-8 stable| Adding PPA} just sits/hangs there.. I am guessing because it expects {ENTER}

What should i do ?

Comment: try adding -vvvv to running your playbook.
By the way, I tried it on a local vagrant machine, and it works fine!
Are you sure you really have a problem?

Comment: Shouldn't your last task be using `state=latest` instead of `state=present`? With `state=present` it just checks to see if ANY version of rsyslog exists.  By using `state=latest` you're telling it to upgrade the package if a newer version exists.

Comment: @BruceP oh yes. i missed it , its state=latest

Comment: @ArnaudPotier i figued out my proxy server were not allowing  this traffic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - my proxy server were not allowing this traffic!

[@NishantSingh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33252538/unable-to-update-rsyslog-using-ansible#comment54474452_33252538)